# Ubuntu BYACC / BTYACC Syntax error

Tags: makefile, yacc

I'm trying to compile the libxkbcommon library for kodi for my Raspberry Pi 2.

The host machine is a dedicated Server running Ubuntu 16.04 x64.

Now there are two errors when I'm trying to compile libxkbcommon, depending on what yacc I'm using:

byacc:

```
YACC     src/xkbcomp/parser.c
yacc: e - line 219 of 
"/opt/kodi/xbmc/tools/depends/target/libxkbcommon/raspberry-pi2-release/src/xkbcomp/parser.y", syntax error
%destructor { FreeStmt((ParseCommon *) $$); }
^
Makefile:1637: recipe for target 'src/xkbcomp/parser.c' failed
```

btyacc:

```
parser.y:85: syntax error
```

Here is the source code of libxkbcommon:

https://github.com/xkbcommon/libxkbcommon

Comment: Probably requires the popular one you didn't try: GNU bison

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `xbcomp/parser.y` file requires a number of (very useful) bison extensions, so it can't be processed by all yacc variants.

- `btyacc` does not support bison-compatible pure-parser declarations. (It has a different, not entirely compatible mechanism which implements the same feature.) So it fails on the first instance of one of those declarations.
- It should be possible to use `byacc`, but not the version which is available in the Ubuntu package repository. Although the Ubuntu package repository change history seems to suggest that the intention was to include the build option which allows `%destructor`, the actual binary currently available in the `byacc` repository was built without that option. (It is also several years old, and I think it would be useful to use a more recent version.) I reported this as [launchpad bug 1776270](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/byacc/+bug/1776270), along with a suggestion for a possible fix.
- I'm sure you'll be able to build the software using Gnu bison, which is available as the Ubuntu package `bison`. Since that's the most popular yacc version installed on developer machines, a failure to build with `bison` would probably have been noticed long ago.

If you would prefer to use `byacc`, for whatever reason, you'll have to download and build it yourself. You can get the most recent version from [Thomas Dickey's byacc page](https://invisible-island.net/byacc/byacc.html#download), and then build it with the usual procedure: untar, configure, make, make install. When I tested this, I used the following configure line:

```
./configure --enable-btyacc  --program-prefix=b  --prefix=/usr
```

Only the first option is mandatory

```
* --program-prefix=b   Install it as `byacc` rather than `yacc`
* --enable-btyacc      Necessary for %destructor support
* --prefix=/usr        Install it in /usr/bin and /usr/man. The default
                       is /usr/local/bin and /usr/local/man, which failed on
                       my Ubuntu install because of a missing -D option in the
                       install command in the Makefile.
```